# UX StackExchange logo is invisible in chat

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, chat

The UX StackExchange logo is white-on-white in the chat room:

[image]

/cc @Jin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's fixed after the next chat build; thanks.